How to count the number of bytes read from bufio.Reader in Golang
I open a file and read from it using bufio.Reader like so
file, err := os.Open(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    utf16bom := unicode.UTF16(unicode.LittleEndian, unicode.UseBOM)
    decoder := transform.NewReader(file, utf16bom.NewDecoder())
    reader := bufio.NewReader(decoder)

    headerLines := make([]string, 0)
    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        line = strings.TrimSpace(line)
        if strings.Contains(line, endOfSectionMark) {
            break
        }
        headerLines = append(headerLines, line)
    }
// n bytes read so far from the buffer? 


How can i find out the number of bytes read so far by reader.ReadString so far?

You can define a custom reader:
type CountingReader struct {
   r     io.Reader
   count int
}

func (cr *CountingReader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := cr.r.Read(p)
    cr.count += n
    return n, err
}

then use it like below in your code:
counter := &CountingReader{
    r: decoder,
}
reader := bufio.NewReader(counter)


But this counts the number of bytes the bufio.Reader has buffered, not the number of bytes I have consumed through reader.ReadString('\n'). this is essentially the same as reader.Buffered() right?

You can use bytesRead := int64(len(line) + 1) to determine the bytes have been read from each line. the +1 is for the \n.

These lines are UTF16 encoded with variable length. 2 or 4 bytes per character. this won't work.
